# @font-face doesn't work at all

Tags: css, font-face

here is my integration code:

```
@font-face {font-family: GETwoMedium;
        src: url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.woff) format('woff'),
             url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.ttf) format('truetype'),
                 font-weight:400;font-style:normal;}
```

and here is how I use it:

```
#primary li a {font-weight:bold;font-size:14px; font-family: GETwoMedium; color:#F5B349;}
```

but the font is not working, I try it with a localhost or even with online website nothing worked, I also tried to add apostrophe around the font-family name the url nothing worked.
You can check it on my website [here](http://khmaseen.org)

file structure:

> ```
> /style.css
> /assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.woff
> /assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.ttf
> ```

Comment: There's no element on your page with a class of `.subjectCat`. :-/

Comment: Ok, this element is not working as well `#primary li a`

Comment: why have you commented out the eot and svg formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've messed up some of your syntax with your comments

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GETwoMedium';
    src: url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.eot);
    src: url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.woff) format('woff'),
         url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.svg) format('svg'),             
         url(assets/font/ge_ss_two_medium.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
}
```